# JavaScript: toggle Hide and Show ancher text through a dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, show-hide

through a dropdown selection I want to show up several anchor `divs` which are normally hidden.

The raw row looks like this

```
    h1 id="rglandwahl"><span style="color: #222222;">Wähle ein Land</span></h1>
    <form id="rgasia" class="dropdownrg" action="#" name="rgasia"><select name="Land">
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Land wählen</option>
    <option value="Indien">Indien</option>
    <option value="Indonsien">Indonesien</option>
    <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
    etc...
    </select></form>
```

`Javascript` looks like below

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleMe(a){ 


    AlleAus() 

    var e = document.getElementById(a); 


    if(!e)return true; 

    // Umschaltung 
    if(e.style.display == "none") 
    { 
     e.style.display = "block" 
     } 
     else 
     { 
     e.style.display = "none" 
     } 

     return true; 
    } 




    function AlleAus() { 
    #Indien.style.display = "none";

    #Indonesien.style.display = "none";

    #Japan.style.display = "none";
    etc...
   }
   </script>
```

I tried many ways like

```
   <option onClick="return toggleMe('Indien')">Indien</option>
```

or

```
   <option onClick="return toggleMe('#Indien')>Indien</option>
```

or

```
  <option onClick="return toggleMe('#Indien')value="#Indien">Indien</option>
```

or
      Indien

or as well

```
   <form id="rgasia" class="dropdownrg" action="#" name="rgasia"><select name="Land" onclick="toggleMe(a)>
```

with the same possibilities like above.

All of them are not providing the outcome i would like to. What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Guten Tag, Thomas.

The main problem that I see with your code is that option elements don't respond to "click" events.  Rather, you will want to use the "change" event on the select element.

Also, it is generally considered to be better form to create the event listener in JavaScript rather than as an attribute in the HTML, although this is a matter of personal preference to some extent.

So here is an example of how you might code this:

```
<script>
var e = document.getElementById("Land"); // You will need to set the "id" attribute of the select element to "Land" in order for this to work.
if (e) {
    e.addEventListener("change", toggleMe);
}

function toggleMe() {
    AlleAus();

    var e = this;
    if(!e)return true; 

    // Umschaltung 
    if(e.style.display == "none") 
    { 
        e.style.display = "block";
    } 
    else 
    { 
        e.style.display = "none";
    } 

    return true; 
}

function AlleAus() { 
    document.getElementById("Indien").style.display = "none";

    document.getElementById("Indonesien").style.display = "none";

    document.getElementById("Japan").style.display = "none";
    etc...
}
</script>
```

You will want to remove any "onClick" attributes that you have added to the option elements in order for the above code to work correctly.

I hope this helps you. Viel Glück!

Comment: Danke dir erstmal, leider funkts. noch nicht.
I changed the attribute to onchange."toggleMe(this.value)", looks like I need to learn more js..

Comment: Do you see any error messages in your debug environment (Chrome Developer Tools, Firebug, etc.)?

Comment: I am now trying to go with the code from studio-klik below, looks simpler for me, so I understand it probably better. His code works in his sandbox, but on my site not and in my sandbox not, but it is the same code, what do you think, what could it be?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hwm3sjzf  /  http://codesheet.org/codesheet/82ahRD4o

Comment: It's probably because he is using jQuery.  You need to make sure that you include the script for jQuery prior to any script that you have written which uses it.  You can use this include from jQuery's CDN:  `<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<span style="color: #222222;">Wähle ein Land</span></h1>
    <form id="rgasia" class="dropdownrg" action="#" name="rgasia">
<select name="Land" onchange="selectCounty(this.value)">
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Land wählen</option>
    <option value="Indien">Indien</option>
    <option value="Indonsien">Indonesien</option>
    <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
   </select>
</form>

<div class="country" id="Indien">Indien</div>
<div class="country" id="Indonsien">Indonsien</div>
<div class="country" id="Japan">Japan</div>
```

Javascript

```
function selectCounty(showme){
    $(".country").hide();
    $("#"+showme).show();
}
```

CSS

```
.country{
    display:none;
}
```

Demo: http://codesheet.org/codesheet/82ahRD4o

Comment: Hi thanks, I tried it, in a sandbox it works but not on my page, I am investigating now why..

Comment: Hi, on codesheet.org your script is working, but not on mine website either  on jsfiddle.com, what you think, is the problem, I tried to link to jsquery, but I havent been able

https://jsfiddle.net/hwm3sjzf/